# Cookie value stored null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, null

```
public double FindSubTotal()
{
    SqlConnection objConnection;
    SqlCommand objCommand;
    string SQL, s;
    double price;
    objConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebsiteAdminConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    objConnection.Open();
    s = "";
    price = 0.0;
    //SQL = "SELECT  isnull(balance, 0) as balance FROM  PurchaseList where productType=3 AND userID =" + Request.Cookies["customerID"].Value + " ";
    SQL = "SELECT  ISNULL(price, 0) as p FROM tempList where  userID=" + Request.Cookies["customerID"].Value;
    objCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, objConnection);
    objCommand.Prepare();
    SqlDataReader objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (objDataReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (objDataReader.Read() == true)
        {
            price = price + Convert.ToDouble(objDataReader["p"]);
        }
    }
    objConnection.Close();
    return price;
}

public string FindDesc()
{
    SqlConnection objConnection;
    SqlCommand objCommand;
    string SQL, s, items;
    double price;
    objConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebsiteAdminConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    objConnection.Open();
    s = "";
    price = 0.0;
    if (Request.Cookies["mycookie"] == null) return "0";   // I added this to remove the cookies and page loads up.
    //SQL = "SELECT  isnull(balance, 0) as balance FROM  PurchaseList where productType=3 AND userID =" + Request.Cookies["customerID"].Value + " ";
    SQL = "SELECT  ISNULL(price, 0) as p, quantity, productName FROM tempList where  userID=" + Request.Cookies["customerID"].Value;
    objCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, objConnection);
    objCommand.Prepare();
    SqlDataReader objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
    items = "";

    if (objDataReader.HasRows)
    {

        while (objDataReader.Read() == true)
        {
            price = Convert.ToDouble(objDataReader["p"]);
            items = items + " DESC: " + Convert.ToString(objDataReader["productName"]).Replace("'","").Replace(@"""","").Replace(@"™","") + " QTY: " + Convert.ToString(objDataReader["quantity"]) + " $" + price.ToString("N");
        }
    }
    objConnection.Close();
    return items;
}
```

This a page - viewbasket.aspx.cs .when i click on viewbasket button it showed error ,found out this is due to a `null` value passed to cookie and used the code -mentioned "to remove cookies" trying to clear it. now i am experiencing an issue because request.cookies is empty and unable to add items to cart as string is getting emptied.

Unique ID has been set already "customerID" for cookies.
Please help me with this anyone, I am not familiar with asp.net. But just need a fix with this. Thanks in advance my friends

Comment: Did you search for your exact error message? By the way, what is the error message received that block your efforts?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
SQL = "SELECT  ISNULL(price, 0) as p, quantity, productName FROM tempList where  userID=" + Request.Cookies["customerID"].Value;

Thanks for the timely response!

Comment: Request.Cookies stored some null value is what i found from my research - If it gives you some ideas.
Thanks